# Which CSS Tags are supported by CHM File?

Tags: css, unicode, chm

does CHM support following CSS tag?

```
li:before { content: "⇨ "; }
```

Answer (score 2):

CHM is shown using HTML Help Viewer. Since HTML Help Viewer uses Internet Explorer's engine to render the file, it depend on which version of IE is installed.

IE8 and later support `:before` and `content`.

Comment: Maybe IE always runs in quirks mode in CHM.

Answer (score 1):

The CHM viewer (hh.exe) essentially runs Internet Explorer 7, so whatever is supported in IE 7 is what you can use in your HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Unfortunately that limits you very much in what you can do and the CSS content: style is one that doesn't work.

You can force the hh.exe to run in a newer IE emulation mode by modifying the registry. More info in this blog post: 
http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/Feb/15/Make-your-CHM-Help-Files-show-HTML5-and-CSS3-content

You can potentially have an installed application make those registry adjustments to globally allow better HTML support - but be aware that that might break other things.

If you need to stick to the default CHM support you can use JavaScript to manipulate the document and dynamically inject content.